# 2-bit counter with reset - non-changing output issue

Tags: vhdl, simulation, fpga

This is the question that I am trying to answer.

> Design and simulate a 2-bit counter which after a reset counts “00”,
>   “01”,“10”, “11”, “00”, “01 ...” synchronously to the clock rising
>   edges.

My code increments the `z` output once and then stops at `01` when I simulate it in `Vivado 2017.2`! What is wrong with my code? Do I need a test bench? If so, how do I know I need a test bench to simulate the code?

Here is my code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity twoc is
Port (reset : in std_logic;
ck : in std_logic;
 z : out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0));
end twoc;

architecture Behavioral of twoc is
signal a : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0):= "00";
signal temp : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
begin 
process(ck)

begin
if ck='1' and ck'event then
    if reset ='1' then
    temp<="00";
    else
    temp <=std_logic_vector(unsigned(a)+1);
    end if;
end if;
end process;
z <= temp;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: A testbench insures portability. IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.2 Elaboration of a design hierarchy "An implementation may allow, but is not required to allow, a design entity at the root of a design hierarchy to have generics and ports. If an implementation allows these top-level interface objects, it may restrict their allowed forms (that is, whether they are allowed to be interface types, subprograms, packages, or objects), and, in the case of interface objects, their allowed types and modes in an implementation-defined manner."  The need can be based on complexity or demonstrating problems/fixes.

Comment: Note how buraquete's answer does not (now) mention the need for type conversion in assigning an unsigned temp to z. A testbench would allow the problem to be replicated and the solution to be validated.

Comment: Here on stackoverflow how quick or accurate an answer can depend on how easily the problem can be reproduced and the solution verified, encouraging the use of a testbench. This also helps future readers encountering the same or similar problems. You'll find higher quality questions and answers useful as references tend to get up votes garnering reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to your assignment of `temp <= unsigned(a) + 1` for all cases, and since `a` is constant with signal `00`, you only output `01`, just drop `a` and use `temp <= unsigned(temp) + 1` with temp initialized to `00`.

As a point of improvement, as [mkrieger1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4621513/mkrieger1) suggests, it'd be better to define `temp` as `unsigned` since you wish to apply `+` on it. Also you'd need to either convert `temp` back to a std logic vector again while you are assigning its value back to `z`, or make `z` `unsigned` as well.

```
signal temp : unsigned(1 downto 0) := "00";
```

Comment: Also, `temp` probably needs to be an `unsigned` instead of a `std_logic_vector` so the `+` operator is defined, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Yeah, I mean just declare it as an `unsigned`, not convert it each time.

Comment: And that would require type conversion of temp to std_logic_vector in the signal assignment to z: `z <= std_logic_vector(temp);`